# UITextFieldDelegate Causes Exception

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Simple Case. I want to create a UIViewController displaying and reacting to the input of a simple UITextField.

1. I created a UIViewController including the **xib** file.
2. In Interface Builder I added a **View** and a containing **UITextField**.
3. The **File's Owner** is set to the according class name that contains the logic "CardViewController".
4. The File Owner points to the View as view.
5. The **text field** uses the **File's Owner** as **delegate**.

It looks like this...

[image]

The view is being displayed correctly, but as soon as I tap the textfield the application crashes with an exception "EXC_BAD_ACCESS...."

My guess is that there's something wrong with the assignement of the delegate, but I have problems finding the issue. Any idea? What did I miss?

---

Further Findings. When I instantiate this viewcontroller directly **in the AppDelegate the delegation of the UITextField actually works!**!

But what I actually plan to do to create an instance of a "BoardViewController" class first which then creates "CardViewController" objects. Having this kind nesting causes the delegation to fail.

As a reference. In my App Delegate:

```
BoardViewController *bvc = [[BoardViewController alloc] init];
[self.window setRootViewController:bvc];
```

in the Board Class I have a "add" button that triggers the creation of the CardViewControllers

```
-(void) addCard:(id)touchEvent{
    NSLog(@"<Board> Add");
    CardViewController *cvc = [[CardViewController alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:cvc.view];
}
```

and then the CardViewController looks as mentioned at first with the delegation being set in the xib.

Comment: Yes. True. Thanks. I forgot to change it after testing to instantiate the CardViewController directly in the AppDelegate.  I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I found my solution. Instead of just adding the view of the CardViewController as subview I also needed to add it as ChildViewController.

In the parent BoardViewController

```
-(void) addCard:(id)touchEvent{
    CardViewController *cvc = [[CardViewController alloc]init];
    [self addChildViewController:cvc];
    [self.view addSubview:cvc.view];
}
```

Then the delegate call works. Yay.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your CardViewController is not initialized. Where do you suggest it should be constructed?

Comment: But it is initialised from another class via "CardViewController *cvc = [[CardViewController alloc]init]; [self.view addSubview:cvc.view];" And it is being displayed. Only when I tap the textfield the app crashes.

Comment: It should be constructed via initWithNibName, since it is stored in nib.

Comment: I thought init should fetch the right nib/xib automatically by the same name. Anyhow I tried "CardViewController *cvc = [[CardViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CardViewController" bundle:nil]". Unfortunately it is still crashing.

Comment: Did you implement any code for UITextViewDelegate protocol? Add outlet for your text field, put breakpoint on controller creation, and check if after this cvc.textField.delegate points to cvc.

Comment: I haven't implemented any delegate methods yet. They are all optional. The issue happens when the delegate is called, not when it is assigned. The assignment of the delegate must be wrong. I am not sure yet if I need to assign it in code AND in the xib or if it shouldn't be enough to link the delegate in the xib file.

Comment: You should assign it xib or in code. However, by doing what I suggested you can check if it is correctly assigned in xib

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your view Controller properly.

```
CardViewController *objCardView = [[CardViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CardViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:objCardView.view];
```

if this is working then check this thing:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization}

    }
    return self;
}
```

this method of your class is working  and then check for ViewDidLoad.

Then you also need to check you have implemented your textField Delegate properly. Intialize your textField with property and make connection File Owner.

Debug Your code using Break Point. I hope this will help you.